# Controlling two DC motors with single driver IC

Tags: motor, dc-motor, motordriver

I've designed a PCB that drives two [DC motors](https://gimsonrobotics.co.uk/categories/dc-electric-motors/products/gr-wm4-24v-dc-high-torque-35rpm-worm-gear-motor) with two MC33886 DC motor Driver ICs, controlled by an MCU for PWM and direction. The max. motor current is about 3.5 A.

It works perfectly but now I'm trying to reduce PCB's BOM cost. Two motors are never running at the same time, so I want to get rid of one DC motor driver IC (as they're pretty expensive, about $13) and control both motors with single IC.

So I need to switch OUT1 and OUT2 the from `+`/`-` terminals of one motor to the terminals of the other.

The only way that comes to mind is using two electro-mechanical relays. Is there a more elegant way to do that, possibly using some kind of solid-state elements?

[image]

Comment: Please can you edit your question to add the motor current (typical and stall), it's impossible to answer without that. Putting mechanical relays aside, I'd imagine that any IC/etc lash-up capable of switching that current would be getting on for as much as another MC33886. You might get a better result from finding a cheaper motor driver and using two of those instead.

Comment: https://www.ectransistors.com/1-PCS-MC33886VW-HSOP-20-MC33886-5-0-A-H-BRIDGE-new.html

Comment: Tony Stewart EE75, IC you suggested is no longer manufactured and is replaced with MC33886PVW that i'm using in my design

Comment: TonyM, thanks for the advice - added the link to motor in initial post

Comment: you're spending £116 on motors and the price of a controller IC is too much? Will the savings per PCB times the sales volume pay for the re-design?

Comment: Well, if the OP is planning serial production of the control boards, it does make sense to try and reduce the cost like this. But if we are speaking about limited quantity of the full systems, including the motors... then yeah, it probably won't worth it.

Comment: user_1818839, Eugene Sh. thanks for your attention for my problem, but let me decide is it worth re-designing or not. If you have something to say on topic you are welcome. JFYI, such kind of motor costs about 17$ if buy directly from manufacturer in China.

Comment: does each motor run in both directions? ... have you considered using only one motor?

Comment: yes, both motors should run in both directions

Comment: You could use one Double Pole (DPDT) relay rather than two single pole relays.